# Notifications for SQL Job when a step fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-agent

Trying to find out if there is a way to setup email notifications when just 1 (or more) steps fail on a sql job.  I have a job with 9 steps, but each step needs to be set to continue to next step even if it fails.  So even when a step fails, because I need it to go to the next step its not set to "report failure". As SQL Server Agent does not have an option for "Report failure and go to next step" I am wondering if anyone has any workarounds for getting a notification

Comment: Can you program the notification in the job steps?

Comment: Considering it'll likely be important to know which step fail, it would seem like a "better" idea to use a `TRY...CATCH` and send the email (by `sp_send_dbmail`) in the `CATCH`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional job step to query the `msdb` tables for steps that failed.  After this, the `sp_send_dbmail` stored procedure can be used to send an email with the errors if any occurred.  The `run_date` column of `SYSJOBHISTORY` is an int column, so the date will be along the format of YYYYMMDD.  The filter below on the `run_status` column will apply to individual steps regardless of the overall job outcome, with 0 indicating a status of failed.

```
DECLARE @JobExecutionDate INT 

--current date
SET @JobExecutionDate = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) AS INT) 


--check if there were any errors first
IF EXISTS (SELECT h.instance_id
FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBHISTORY h 
         INNER JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBS j ON h.job_id = j.job_id 
         INNER JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBSTEPS s ON j.job_id = s.job_id AND h.step_id = s.step_id
WHERE h.run_status = 0 AND h.run_date = @JobExecutionDate AND j.name = 'YourJobName')

BEGIN

DECLARE @Title VARCHAR(50)

SET @Title = CONCAT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE), 109), ' Job Error Email')


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  
    @profile_name = 'Your Database Mail Profile',  
    @recipients = 'ExampleEmail@Domain.com',  
@query = 'SELECT  j.[name] AS JobName,  
         s.step_name AS StepName,  
         h.run_date AS RunDate, 
         h.run_time AS RunTime, 
         h.sql_severity As ErrorSeverity, 
         h.message AS ErrorMessage
FROM MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBHISTORY h 
         INNER JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBS j ON h.job_id = j.job_id 
         INNER JOIN MSDB.DBO.SYSJOBSTEPS s ON j.job_id = s.job_id AND h.step_id = s.step_id
WHERE h.run_status = 0 AND h.run_date = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112) AS INT) AND j.name = ''YourJobName''
',
  @query_result_no_padding = 1,
    @subject = @Title ;


END
```

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. We are still using SQL 2008 so CONCAT is not a function for us.  Just got rid of CONCAT and added a plus sign between DATE and ' Job Error Email'  -- Just figured I'd mention that if others using SQL 2008 try to implement this.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Good to hear.  Only thing to keep in mind is that when strings are added together using a + sign the entire string will be null if one of them is.  Since this is only concatenating GETDATE() and static text it won't be an issue, but otherwise just make sure to account for nulls with COALESCE.